# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.state.params.datas.map)

Tags: react-native

*I send data from page2 component to page1 component like this :*

> this.props.navigation.navigate('Page1', { datas: alldata });
>
> I take data in page1 like this :

```
  constructor(props) {
                super(props);

                this.props.navigation.state.params.datas.map(color => {
                    if(color.Renk == 'MAVI'){
                        console.log("mavi");
                        Blue.push("MAVI");
                    }
                    else if(color.Renk == 'SARI')
                    {
                        Yellow.push("SARI")
                    }
                })
              }
```

*everything is ok when debug mode. I can take all datas. but when debug mode is enable it gives me that error which is on title*

Comment: Have you tried accessing it in a lifecycle method, like componentDidMount() or even in render()? I think it's undefined just 'cause you are in constructor

Comment: But when in debug, it doesnt give me error